# Switch statement with non-constant cases

Tags: java, command-line, internationalization, switch-statement

Im working on this assignment, in which im using a command line interface. Im using a simple switch statement to create the controls to this command line interface, however when I added internationalisation support as part of my assignment, my switch statement has broken due to the variables within needing to be constant. How do I get around this?

```
public class Editor {

    private boolean running = true;

    public static ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();

    Locale enLocale = new Locale("en", "GB");
    ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("BaseBundle", enLocale);
    String open = messages.getString("open");
    String saveas = messages.getString("saveas");
    String put = messages.getString("put");
    String rot90 = messages.getString("rot90");
    String mono = messages.getString("mono");
    String help = messages.getString("help");
    String quit = messages.getString("quit");
    String look = messages.getString("look");
    String undo = messages.getString("undo");
    private String get = messages.getString("get");

    Parser parser = new Parser();

    public Editor() {
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("fotoshop");
        while (running) {
            command = parser.readInput();
            interpret(command);
        }
        System.out.println("fotoshop exiting");
    }

    public void interpret(ArrayList<String> command) {


        switch (command.get(0)) {
            case open: OpenCommand.execute();
            case saveas: SaveCommand.execute();
            case put: PutCommand.execute();
            case get: GetCommand.execute();
            case rot90: ApplyRot90.execute();
            case mono: ApplyMono.execute();
            case help: HelpCommand.execute();
            case quit: running = false;
            case look: LookCommand.execute();
            case undo;

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: You can't. Use a `Map` or some other lookup datastructure for your commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a if else statement

**Example**

```
String com = command.get(0);
if (com.equals(open)) {
    OpenCommand.execute()
} else if (com.equals(saveas)) {
    SaveCommand.execute();
} ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with internationalization in Java, but I think the general pattern you should be using is something like this:

```
Map<String, String> i18Map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("open", "open");    // English
map.put("abierto", "open"); // Spanish
map.put("ouvrir", "open");  // French
// other words/languages
```

In other words, maintain some sort of map which can map a command, in any language you want to support, to a command English language command.  Then, refactor your `switch` statement to switch on those English language constants instead of variables:

```
String input = parser.readInput();
String command = i18Map.get(input);

switch (command.get(0)) {
    case "open": OpenCommand.execute();
    case "saveas": SaveCommand.execute();
    case "put": PutCommand.execute();
    case "get": GetCommand.execute();
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the following trick to implement dynamic switch?
It might be an overkill but it is worth having a look.

You can define it with String instead of Integer to map it to the different actions in the different languages your application should support.

[java-tip-3-how-to-implement-dynamic-switch](https://coderwall.com/p/wgtifw/java-tip-3-how-to-implement-dynamic-switch)

```
class Switcher {

    private Map<Integer, Command> caseCommands;

    private Command defaultCommand;

    private Command getCaseCommandByCaseId(Integer caseId) {
        if (caseCommands.containsKey(caseId)) {
            return caseCommands.get(caseId);
        } else {
            return defaultCommand;
        }
    }

    public Switcher() {
        caseCommands = new HashMap<Integer, Command>();

        setDefaultCaseCommand(new DoNothingCommand());
    }

    public void addCaseCommand(Integer caseId, Command caseCommand) {
        caseCommands.put(caseId, caseCommand);
    }

    public void setDefaultCaseCommand(Command defaultCommand) {
        if (defaultCommand != null) {
            this.defaultCommand = defaultCommand;
        }
    }

    public void on(Integer caseId) {
        Command command = getCaseCommandByCaseId(caseId);

        command.execute();
    }
}
```

Your Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Switcher switcher = new Switcher();
        switcher.addCaseCommand(1, new Command() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Command on {id: 1}");
            }
        });
        switcher.addCaseCommand(2, new Command() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Command on {id: 2}");
            }
        });
        switcher.addCaseCommand(3, new Command() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Command on {id: 3}");
            }
        });
        switcher.setDefaultCaseCommand(new Command() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Command on {default}");
            }
        });

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            switcher.on(i);
        }
    }
}
```

// output

```
Command on {id: 1}
Command on {id: 2}
Command on {id: 3}
Command on {default}
```

**Or even better to avoid having all the messages directly hardcoded in the hashmap**, and by consequence having to recompile change the code when adding new language support

> **Internationalizing the Sample Program**
>
> If you look at the internationalized source code, you'll notice that
>   the hardcoded English messages have been removed. Because the messages
>   are no longer hardcoded and because the language code is specified at
>   run time, the same executable can be distributed worldwide. No
>   recompilation is required for localization. The program has been
>   internationalized.
>
> You may be wondering what happened to the text of the messages or what
>   the language and country codes mean. Don't worry. You'll learn about
>   these concepts as you step through the process of internationalizing
>   the sample program.
>
> **1. Create the Properties Files**
>
> A properties file stores information about the characteristics of a
>   program or environment. A properties file is in plain-text format. You
>   can create the file with just about any text editor.
>
> In the example the properties files store the translatable text of the
>   messages to be displayed. Before the program was internationalized,
>   the English version of this text was hardcoded in the
>   `System.out.println` statements. The default properties file, which is
>   called MessagesBundle.properties, contains the following lines:
>
> `greetings = Hello` 
>   `farewell = Goodbye` 
>   `inquiry = How are you?` Now that
>   the messages are in a properties file, they can be translated into
>   various languages. No changes to the source code are required. The
>   French translator has created a properties file called
>   `MessagesBundle_fr_FR.properties`, which contains these lines:
>
> `greetings = Bonjour.` 
>   `farewell = Au revoir.` 
>   `inquiry = Comment`
>   allez-vous? Notice that the values to the right side of the equal sign
>   have been translated but that the keys on the left side have not been
>   changed. These keys must not change, because they will be referenced
>   when your program fetches the translated text.
>
> The name of the properties file is important. For example, the name of
>   the `MessagesBundle_fr_FR.properties` file contains the fr language code
>   and the FR country code. These codes are also used when creating a
>   Locale object.
>
> **2. Define the Locale**
>
> The Locale object identifies a particular language and country. The
>   following statement defines a Locale for which the language is English
>   and the country is the United States:
>
> `aLocale = new Locale("en","US");` The next example creates Locale
>   objects for the French language in Canada and in France:
>
> `caLocale = new Locale("fr","CA");` `frLocale = new Locale("fr","FR");`
>   **The program is flexible.** Instead of using hardcoded language and
>   country codes, the program gets them from the command line at run
>   time:
>
> `String language = new String(args[0]);` 
>   `String country = new String(args[1]);` 
>   `currentLocale = new Locale(language, country);` Locale
>   objects are only identifiers. After defining a Locale, you pass it to
>   other objects that perform useful tasks, such as formatting dates and
>   numbers. These objects are locale-sensitive because their behavior
>   varies according to Locale. A ResourceBundle is an example of a
>   locale-sensitive object.
>
> **3. Create a ResourceBundle**
>
> ResourceBundle objects contain locale-specific objects. You use
>   ResourceBundle objects to isolate locale-sensitive data, such as
>   translatable text. In the sample program the ResourceBundle is backed
>   by the properties files that contain the message text we want to
>   display.
>
> The ResourceBundle is created as follows:
>
> messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);
>   The arguments passed to the getBundle method identify which properties
>   file will be accessed. The first argument, MessagesBundle, refers to
>   this family of properties files:
>
> MessagesBundle_en_US.properties MessagesBundle_fr_FR.properties
>   MessagesBundle_de_DE.properties The Locale, which is the second
>   argument of getBundle, specifies which of the MessagesBundle files is
>   chosen. When the Locale was created, the language code and the country
>   code were passed to its constructor. Note that the language and
>   country codes follow MessagesBundle in the names of the properties
>   files.
>
> Now all you have to do is get the translated messages from the
>   ResourceBundle.
>
> **4. Fetch the Text from the ResourceBundle**
>
> The properties files contain key-value pairs. The values consist of
>   the translated text that the program will display. You specify the
>   keys when fetching the translated messages from the ResourceBundle
>   with the getString method. For example, to retrieve the message
>   identified by the greetings key, you invoke getString as follows:
>
> String msg1 = messages.getString("greetings"); The sample program uses
>   the key greetings because it reflects the content of the message, but
>   it could have used another String, such as s1 or msg1. Just remember
>   that the key is hardcoded in the program and it must be present in the
>   properties files. If your translators accidentally modify the keys in
>   the properties files, getString won't be able to find the messages.
>
> **Conclusion**
>
> That's it. As you can see, internationalizing a program isn't too
>   difficult. It requires some planning and a little extra coding, but
>   the benefits are enormous. To provide you with an overview of the
>   internationalization process, the sample program in this lesson was
>   intentionally kept simple. As you read the lessons that follow, you'll
>   learn about the more advanced internationalization features of the
>   Java programming language.

Source official doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/steps.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a `Map` where the keys are the internationalised strings, and the values are the commands that you want executed.  So assuming that all the various `Command` classes (`OpenCommand`, `SaveCommand` and so on) have a common subtype `Command` where the `execute` method is declared, you could prime the map like this.

```
Map<String,Command> commandsByInternationalisedString = new HashMap<String,Command>();
Locale enLocale = new Locale("en", "GB");
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("BaseBundle", enLocale);

commandsByInternationalisedString.add(messages.getString("open"), new OpenCommand());
commandsByInternationalisedString.add(messages.getString("saveas"), new SaveAsCommand());
commandsByInternationalisedString.add(messages.getString("put"), new PutCommand());
```

So now you have a map with a `Command` object corresponding to any command the user might enter.  To use it, you could do this.

```
public void interpret(ArrayList<String> command) {

    Command toExecute = commandsByInternationalisedString.get(command.get(0));
    if (toExecute != null ) {
        toExecute.execute();
    } else {
        System.out.println("That's not a valid command");
    }
}
```